# Wordpress rest api not closing browser session

Tags: wordpress, rest

When I call a rest route, the browser session is not closed and the browser keeps loading. Due to this, chrome generates `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error.

Here is the request header:

```
GET /?rest_route=/test/v1/advertiser/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: www.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dhtml; wp-settings-time-1=1499682179; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_dc4e3a2222d11ce1c897e40579a199d39=admin%7C1501067732%7CgpNTUVy5lddq6EDTuDg6YzR9G2F222220zRTbEsgVTRF9%7C11627a0ad7e00c5d4f0a1b8a822d6ac366da838d7648c3d5c7cf7826eb5eb856
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
```

And here is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 04:48:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <_domain_url_here_/?rest_route=/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Allow: GET
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 04:48:00 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

If there is anything else I need to post here, please let me know.

Comment: Looks like this issue occurs only with my computer, another office mate checked it and it works fine. This could be a chrome or network issue. Because the other person who checked was on different network.